# Does $\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$ embed into $\omega_1$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

$\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$ has the lexicographic ordering.

By embedding, I mean an order preserving map from $\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$

Comment: No, it does not: it’s not well-ordered, as you can see by considering just $\Bbb Z^-\times\{0\}$.

Comment: Does this essentially ask if $\omega_1\cdot\omega$ is the same ordinal as $\omega_1$?

Comment: @BrianTung: No, it doesn’t.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Then I guess I'm not sure I understand what is meant by lexicographic ordering here.

Comment: @BrianTung: $\langle p,\alpha\rangle\preceq\langle q,\beta\rangle$ iff $p<q$, or $p=q$ and $\alpha\le\beta$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: (I suspect the UI is going to ask me to push to chat at any moment, but) I'm probably betraying my ignorance here, but then don't we essentially have $\omega$ "consecutive" copies of $\omega_1$?

Comment: @BrianTung: No, we have $\omega$ copies of $\omega_1$ **ordered like** $\Bbb Q$, not like $\omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ahh, that was my confusion.  I was imagining a well-ordering of $\mathbb{Q}$, and then using *that* as the lexical basis.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That should be an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not: it’s not well-ordered, as you can see by considering just the subset $\Bbb Z^-\times\{0\}$.